# CellForRowAt function throwing an error when accessing an array on each row?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableViewController which has 4 cells.  Each cell is loaded from a xib file in my viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let itemPreBasketServer = ItemPreBasketServer()
    let searchForIDServer = SearchForIDServer()

    let descCell = UINib(nibName: "PreDescTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(descCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "descCell")

    let priceCell = UINib(nibName: "PrePriceTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(priceCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "priceCell")

    let quantityCell = UINib(nibName: "PreQuantityTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(quantityCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "quantityCell")

    let submitCell = UINib(nibName: "PreSubmitTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(submitCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "submitCell")

    if incomeName != "" {
        characterSet.insert(charactersIn: "=\"#%/<>?@\\^`{|}&")
        incomeType = incomeType.replacingOccurrences(of: "&", with: "%26")
        incomeType = incomeType.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "%27")
        incomeName = incomeName.replacingOccurrences(of: "&", with: "%26")
        incomeName = incomeName.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "%27")
        searchForIDServer.name = incomeName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: characterSet)!
        searchForIDServer.type = incomeType.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: characterSet)!
        searchForIDServer.delegate = self
        searchForIDServer.downloadItems()
    } else {
        searchForIDServer.name = incomeName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: characterSet)!
        itemPreBasketServer.id = String(incomeID)
        itemPreBasketServer.delegate = self
        itemPreBasketServer.downloadItems()
    }
}
```

I also have an array called cellItems which is populated by a protocol in either the searchForIDServer.downloaditems() or itemPreBaskeyServer.downloaditems():

```
var cellItems: NSArray = NSArray() {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {
    cellItems = items
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now the problem I have is, in my cellForRowAt function, when ever I create a var on the cellItems I get an error:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item: ItemPreBasketModel = cellItems[indexPath.row] as! ItemPreBasketModel
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {

        //This will be the desc
        let descCell: PreDescTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "descCell", for: indexPath)as! PreDescTableViewCell
        print(item.name)
        return descCell
    } else if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        //This will be the price
        let priceCell: PrePriceTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "priceCell", for: indexPath)as! PrePriceTableViewCell
        return priceCell
    } else if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 2 {
        //This will be the quantity
        let quantityCell: PreQuantityTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "quantityCell", for: indexPath)as! PreQuantityTableViewCell
        return quantityCell
    } else {
        //Submit
        let submitCell: PreSubmitTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "submitCell", for: indexPath)as! PreSubmitTableViewCell
        return submitCell
    }
}
```

The error I get at runtime is:

```
    2018-01-31 16:41:28.884725+0000 SpiceCentral[5487:468249] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a0912b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101b50f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102a21ebd -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:] + 93
    3   SpiceCentral                        0x00000001011ba494 _T012SpiceCentral32ItemPreBasketTableViewControllerC05tableG0So07UITableG4CellCSo0jG0C_10Foundation9IndexPathV12cellForRowAttF + 132
    4   SpiceCentral                        0x00000001011bb0dc _T012SpiceCentral32ItemPreBasketTableViewControllerC05tableG0So07UITableG4CellCSo0jG0C_10Foundation9IndexPathV12cellForRowAttFTo + 92
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000103521484 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 778
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000103521a2a -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001034e71f6 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3031
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001035092e6 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000103491a6d -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1439
    10  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c45f61c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 159
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c4637ad _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 401
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c3ea86c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 364
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c417946 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 500
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001033ea167 _afterCACommitHandler + 272
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001029abc07 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001029abb5e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102990124 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010298f889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000108e869c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001033c05d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    21  SpiceCentral                        0x00000001011c1ec7 main + 55
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010749bd81 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I've tried everything to figure this out but having no luck.  I'm populating other tableviews in exactly the same way in other viewcontrollers, the only difference with this one is that im pre defining my cell count as 4, and I'm also using some logic in my ViewDidLoad.  I'm essentially saying "Hey viewController, if you don't have the ID already, go and get it by running this function which will populate my cellItems, otherwise if you have the ID, run this function.

Comment: Please add the method `numberOfRows`. By the way: Do not use `NSArray` in Swift. You throw away the important type information. And the `section` seems to be irrelevant, why do you check for it in `cellForRow` ?

Comment: It's not a matter of luck. Debug! You have a wonderful debugger; use it. The error message clearly tells you what the problem is: you ask for the item at index 0 in an array that contains no items. That's illegal. The debugger will readily show you what array this is, and you can then think about why _you_ think it is populated when in fact it is not.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "pre defining my cell count as 4"? If you define the following method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
}
```

then it looks logical, you get an error. At the very beginning the `cellItems` array is empty, but the `cellForRowAt` method will be called, because `numberOfRowsInSection` is 4. `cellItems[indexPath.row]` will throw an error, because the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->

 Int {
        if( cellItems?.count < 4 ) return 0
        return 4
        /* Note: If cellItems will always have 4 items when it's loaded, the following line would be appropriate on its own: */
        // return cellItems?.count
 }
```